# Which Data Structure I should prefer for the given kind of data and its use

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am creating a Java project using PDFBox API to create a graph. I have to make my graph totally configurable. I have achieved everything how it will happen. And also what will be input for that. **But I am not able to decide which Data Structure I should use for input data.**

My input data

___________________________________________
| Label 1 (Y - axis) |  Label 2 (X - axis) |
|____________________|_____________________|
|     Work A         | 20                  |
|     Work B         | 30                  |
|     Work C         | 50                  |
|     Work D         | 10                  |
|     Work E         | 27                  |
|____________________|_____________________|

***Sorry for representation of data***

The graph will be having horizontal bars.

Order of this data remains the same.

I am able to find the maximum value of all values (from Label 2 easily).

Any guess??

Answer (score 0):

If I were You, I would use LinkedHashMap.
Why?

1. It maintains insertion order
2. You can easily get any element of it in O(1) time
3. If a key is reinserted into a map, insertion order would not be affected

Also, getting all elements from the map is iterating through each entry, so it would look like sth like this:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet())
{
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue());
}
```

EDIT:

According to comments, even simple ArrayList, which would contain a pair of work and value would be good. You can easily store the current maximum while adding elements to it, and then you wouldn't need to waste time finding one. The only thing, that I would suggest is that you provide size because ArrayList only grows by 50% and starts with the default size of 10. Also, if you want to add an element to ArrayList one by one, do it with simple method add, to add it to the end.

Comment: IMO for a graph plot it's not required to maintain the insertion order. In context of data mentioned in the question it doesn' t matter if API gets (20,WORK A) before (10, WORK D). Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: So you are saying, that input order doesn't matter and for example, your indexes would be sorted alphabetically right? In such a situation, even simple list which would contain pairs(work and value) would be good. Could you provide an example of usage? What would be the most using and frequently used case in your program? Finding minimum or adding more elements? Or iterating?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I think data representation is more important irrespective of the order of data @YugSingh

Comment: I will not add or manipulate anything in this dataset. I just want to find max value from this dataset because I want to set length of x-axis according to that @Ajris

Comment: I made an edit, according to these comments @HardikSaraf